# spark driver memory consumption

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an application which submits multiple spark applications in parallel in client mode. What are the guidelines I need to follow to write the spark application such that driver memory is not overflown.

The operations I am doing in the spark are as follows:
val df1 : read data from file to dataframe
val df2 : do sum(col4) sum(col5) on df1
val df3 : sort df2 on col2
val df4 : df3.limit(threshould)
val result : fill in Null spaces with literals
save(write) result into file

I am creating multiple data frames here. Are all those data frames brought back to driver program? Will doing multiple operations in one step would make it client(driver) memory efficient?

I read https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html but did not get answer to my question.